# How can I look for two specific characters in a string?

Tags: java, string, design-patterns, char

```
String abc = "||:::|:|::";
```

It should return true if there's two `|` and three `:` appearances.
I'm not sure how to use "regex" or if it's the right method to use. There's no specific pattern in the `abc` String.

Comment: Do you mean it should return `true` if it contains `||:::` or if it contains `||` and `:::` regardless of order or position (`:::||` or `:||:|:::` ...)?

Comment: true, if it contains | and : regardless of position

Comment: Is `":|:|:"` also correct (it contains two `|` and three `:`)?

Comment: yeah as long as there's two | and three :::

Comment: Are there any other constrains? Can string contain only `|` and `:` characters?

Comment: I have to determine if the String is valid meaning if it contains fourteen "|" and 18 ":" in the inputted String. I'm not sure how to do that

Comment: @user3413152 why did you not put that in the question ?

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming you are looking for two '|' to be one after the other and the same for the three ':'
and one follows the other .Do it using the following single regular expressions.

```
".*||.*:::.*"
```

If you are looking to just check the presence of characters and their irrespective of their order then use `String.matches` method using the two regular expressions with a logical AND

```
".*|.*|.*"

".*:.*:.*:.*"
```

Here is a [cheat sheet for regular expressions](http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1). Its fairly simple to learn. Look at groups and quantifiers in the document to understand the above expression.

Comment: Who says that `||` must be placed before `:::`? In [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26746658/how-can-i-look-for-two-specific-characters-in-a-string#comment42078572_26746658) OP claims "contains | and : regardless of position".

Answer (score 0):

Using a regex would be a bad idea, especially if there's no specific order to them. Make a function that counts the number of times a character sppears in a string, and use that:

```
public int count(String base, char toFind)
{
    int count = 0;
    char[] haystack = base.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < haystack.length; i++)
        if (haystack[i] == toFind)
            count++;
    return count; 
}

String abc = "||:::|:|::";
if (count(abc,"|") >= 2 && count(abc,":") >= 3)
{
    //Do some code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My favorite method for searching for the number of characters in a string is `int num = s.length() - s.replaceAll("|","").length();` you can do that for both and test those ints.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test all conditions in one regex you can use [look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead) `(?=condition)`.

Your regex can look like

```
String regex =
        "(?=(.*[|]){2})"//contains two |
        + "(?=(.*:){3})"//contains three :
        + "[|:]+";//is build only from : and | characters
```

Now you can use it with `matches` like

```
String abc = "||:::|:|::";
System.out.println(abc.matches(regex));//true

abc = "|::::::";
System.out.println(abc.matches(regex));//false
```

---

Anyway I you can avoid regex and write your own method which will calculate number of `|` and `:` in your string and check if this numbers are greater or equal to 2 and 3. You can use `StringUtils.countMatches` from [apache-commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) so your test code could look like

```
public static boolean testString(String s){
    int pipes = StringUtils.countMatches(s, "|");
    int colons = StringUtils.countMatches(s, ":");
    return pipes>=2 && colons>=3;
}
```

or

```
public static boolean testString(String s){
    return      StringUtils.countMatches(s, "|")>=2 
            &&  StringUtils.countMatches(s, ":")>=3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested it, but this should work

```
Pattern.compile("^(?=.*[|]{2,})(?=.*[:]{3,})$");
```

The entire string is read by `?=.*` and checked wether the allowed characters (`|`) occurs at least twice. The same is then done for `:`, only that this has to match at least three times.